# How can I remove scores or ban users from Google Play leaderboards?

Tags: leaderboards, google-play

I have included Google Play game services in my Android game. I see lot of users posting fake scores.

Can I ban them or can I delete these scores somehow?

Comment: Probably something you want to talk to Google about. Also, there are a number of questions on this site about preventing cheating. You might want to look into a few of those to learn about some ways you can make it harder for people to post fake scores. Further, I edited your question a bit. The title was asking something different than the body and I made it slightly more specific to Google Play because, as I said, there are a number of questions here already about self made leaderboards that will have different answers than the Google Play leaderboards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the Google REST API [gamesManagement.players.hide](https://developers.google.com/games/services/management/api/players/hide) to hide a player from your applications leaderboard.

Comment: What's the easiest way to get the player ID for the player I want to hide?

Answer (score 2):

For future strugglers as this is not well documented. You can hide players by adding a web application in your Google Play Console and using the [OAuth Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/), to execute the REST APIs [Scores: list](https://developers.google.com/games/services/web/api/scores/list) and [Players: hide](https://developers.google.com/games/services/management/api/players/hide) to get player ids and hiding her/him.

For a thorough walkthrough see my article: https://gaute.app/dev-blog/gpgs-hide-player

Answer (score 0):

You can use this tool to hide cheaters:

https://github.com/playgameservices/management-tools

Comment: Link is broken.

Comment: Here is an updated link: https://github.com/playgameservices/management-tools